# Firmware error on both my laptops since last month(Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: boot, grub2, dell, hardware, firmware

I'm getting this firmware error on both my laptops since past one month or so. Note that I haven't made any new updates since past 2 months.[image]

I don't understand what it means. I'm 99% sure that there is no hardware problem. If there was then why would both my laptops start showing the same error around the same time? Should I be worried? I haven't done anything about it and my it boots up just fine after a few seconds of this error. Asking for Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Have you installed the newest available UEFI/BIOS from vendor for your system? Many have need that for various virus fixes.

Comment: The one in the picture is Dell Vostro 15 3568 and another one Dell 5559. Both having the same issue. So, it's likely that it's an operating system issue. That's all I know, the specifications call be looked up by googling the laptop names. I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: My new Dell just suggested major UEFI and driver updates for the Windows side. Both UEFI & operating systems need updates for Spectre, repoline, RETBleed virus. Firmware bug suggests UEFI issue. Dell  Inspiron 3670 UEFI update & AHCI worked
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2412152